# Posição dos blocos em Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá,
Eu estou tentando fazer um template em bootstrap (devido a sua responsividade) porém estou preso em uma situação que não consigo achar saída sem usar javascript (o que seria péssimo no meu caso).

Eu preciso que o template fique, em telas grandes, como o seguinte Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hsCw9/1/

E em telas pequenas como: http://jsfiddle.net/hsCw9/2/

Caso não tenha sido claro, nas telas pequenas e super pequenas, os blocos "p1" e "p2" tem que sair da lateral direita para **depois** da notícia enquanto o primeiro bloco tem que vir **antes** da notícia; Já nas telas médias para cima, os blocos "p1", "p2" e "stuff" devem vir ao lado direito da notícia.

Não consegui achar alguma solução sem ser com javascript.
Alguma ideia?

PS:: Não se esqueça de re-dimensionar as visualizações no fiddle para que fique do modo correto

Comment: Tu queres que o primeiro bloco da coluna-direita fique antes do primeiro bloco da coluna-esquerda quando em dispositivos de menor resolução?

Comment: Sim, o primeiro bloco da esquerda deve ficar antes e o segundo bloco depois em dispositivos de pequena resolução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Pelo que eu entendi acho que consegui o que você quer:

Primeiro eu tirei as classes `col-push` e `col-pull` que você tinha colocado, troquei pelas classes originais do bootstrap `pull-left` e `pull-right`.

Segundo criei um container para os `<p>`, e coloquei as mesmas classes do "stuff".

Veja o código:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 pull-right">
    <div class="teemo-block">
        p1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 pull-right">
    <div class="teemo-block">
        p2
    </div>
</div>
```

Por padrão todos os "cols" no bootstrap tem float left, então se você quiser diferente tem que forçar isso.

Então a notícia coloquei `pull-left` o resto coloquei `pull-right`, tudo dentro da mesma `row`.

#### O resultado é esse:

http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/hsCw9/6/

Ajudei?

Comment: Pra ficar mais fácil de entender deixei a classe "col-xs-12", porém como nosso amigo Henrique disse o bootstrap faz isso por padrão.

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava! Muito obrigado! :)

Comment: Repostei e traduzi a sua resposta na pergunta do SO em inglês. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467595/columns-position-on-bootstrap/22489678#22489678

Comment: Legal, pena que não acumula ponto, hehe, vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar as [opções de grade](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) para posicionar os elementos da maneira desejada, adequando em função do dispositivo em que são exibidos.

No exemplo abaixo, você terá somente uma coluna em dispositivos mínimos e pequenos, e duas colunas em dispositivos médios e grandes:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">notícia</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">p1 p2 stuff</div>
```

Outra alternativa é utilizar as [classes utilitárias](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) para exibir ou esconder os elementos em função do dispositivo em que são exibidos, mas isso poderia incorrer em repetição de conteúdo.

Comment: Desnecessário declarar `col-xs-12` e `col-sm-12`, pois o comportamento padrão do bootstrap será empilhar o conteúdo caso não haja nada declarado.

Comment: Acho que não houve a compreensão correta do problema nesse caso, pois o problema é a variação da posição dos blocos no template, uma hora o "p1 p2" devem ficar depois do bloco de notícia e em outro momento antes do bloco.

Comment: Respondi lá, dá uma olhada!